# JSON property of Enum type does not like `null` check

Tags: json, angular, typescript, enums, null

In my Angular application, I have a very simple `enum` named `AlertType`. I also have an API response object and one of its properties is of this `enum` type. Like below:

```
export class ScanAlertModel {
    public alertId: string;
    public alertType: AlertType
}
```

I have certain scenarios in which this `alertType` property is not set. I am attempting to test those using `Jasmine`. In my Angular application, to be able to filter an `Array<AlertModel>` for `alert` that do not have an `alerttype` attached to them, I am simply able to apply a filter like below:

`this.scanAlerts.filter((a) => ((a.alertType === null)`

This works ok. But, my tests that attempt to test this filtering (as part of a bigger functional test) fail to filter out records correctly, when my JSON contains `ScanAlertModel` entities that do not have `alertType` at all.

Clearly, this has confused me. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if `alertType` is sometimes not present, declare it as optional with `:?`, like so:

```
export class ScanAlertModel {
    public alertId: string;
    public alertType?: AlertType;
}
```

The reason your filter doesn't always work is that if the property is *not set*, it will not be strictly equal to `null`.

A better check would be to use [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
this.scanAlerts.filter(alert => !alert.hasOwnProperty('alertType'));
```